# How to create JSONP(script) to make Netsuite Request to other server for response?

Tags: javascript, jsonp, netsuite

I just created an portlet in net suite interface. In that portlet currently i'm showing details of the logged in user. Now i need to make an ajax call to my server. Where i can check that the current user is logged in my domain also or not. If not i need to make him log in. Its kind of auto log in when he logs in into net suite interface.

Possible choices.

1. Ajax call(But it will only work in server inside pages, except jsonp) request.
2. iFrame to do it (Note: Its a bad idea anyway i think).

Need help on it.

Thanks in advance

**Vivek Keviv**

Comment: Hi @Quentin can you please provide the link of the duplicate question to that i can get the answers from it. I didn't get solution outside thats why i asked here.

Comment: It's at the top of the question

Comment: Hi @Quentin, i don't know how can this be solution for my question. There the answer is only for how to do JSONP, But i'm asking JSONP integrating with netsuite and suitescript.

Comment: That tells you how to implement JSONP in general terms. If you have a specific problem implementing it, then I think you'll need to elaborate on where you are having the problem.

Comment: Okay sure i'll make the question in elaborate. Thanks for the tips :)